# How could I make it object-oriented

Tags: javascript, oop

I have a js file which use Storage API. It just save form infos to get them if you have to fill the form again in a new session. It also re-use these infos to put them somewhere else in the page without page refreshing. It's working but I would like to make this in an object-oriented way.

Tried to learn OOP (beginner) and to make a function with the code which isn't in an object working at a window.onload event.

```
// STORAGE

// Used Elements
let input_textarea = document.querySelector('#firstname_area');
let input_textarea_bis = document.querySelector('#lastname_area');
let chosen_station = document.querySelector('#station')
let output_div = document.querySelector('.personal-greeting');
let output_station = document.querySelector('#custumerstation'); 
let save_button = document.querySelector('.send');

// Onclick start function
save_button.addEventListener('click', updateOutput);

// Saved Elements
output_div.textContent = localStorage.getItem('content');
input_textarea.value = localStorage.getItem('content');
input_textarea_bis.value = localStorage.getItem('contentbis');
chosen_station.innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem('content');

// Function actions setting saved elements
function updateOutput() {
  localStorage.setItem('content', input_textarea.value);
  localStorage.setItem('contentbis', input_textarea_bis.value);
  output_div.textContent = input_textarea.value;
  output_station.textContent = chosen_station.innerHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By creating a `FormInformation` class you could create `attributes` for the things you need to repeat elsewhere in your app like `input` text area fields, etc... This way, you could store an instance of `FormInformation` and set the attributes with the values of what you got while doing `document.querySelector()` and reuse it